# *IE6 Only*: There's no scrollbar to push down the footer... Relative parent> Absolute child > Relative child

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment, internet-explorer-6

noreply@nosalvation.org

**IE7 and newer won't display.**

In the code below (shown in GIF example), the vertical alignment method is "*hacky*" and **only** displays content in **legacy browsers** like IE6.

[image: My problem: the text content overlaps the header and footer instead of pushing the footer down.]

**The Three Problems:**

***1.*** Content overlaps the header.

***2.*** Content doesn't push the footer down.

***3.*** No scrollbar appears. Instead, the content disappears off the page.

---

The *IE6 and older-only* code:

```
            body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            p {
                font-size: 21px;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #wrapper {
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                margin-bottom: -50px;
                position: relative;
            }
            .header {
                height: 50px;
                background-color: aqua;
            }
            .vcenter-relative-parent {
                height: auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
            }
            .vcenter-absolute {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
            }
            .vcenter-relative-child {
                margin-top: -50px;
                position: relative;
                top: -50%;
            }
            #footer {
                height: 50px;
                background-color: tomato;
            }
            .push { 
                height: 50px;
                position: relative;
                clear: both;
            }
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="header">

            </div>
            <div class="vcenter-relative-parent">
                <div class="vcenter-absolute">
                    <div class="vcenter-relative-child">

                        <p>
                            If you shorten the page height...<br>the content appears under the header and footer...<br>and there's no scrollbar.<br>
                            If you shorten the page height...<br>the content appears under the header and footer...<br>and there's no scrollbar.<br>
                            If you shorten the page height...<br>the content appears under the header and footer...<br>and there's no scrollbar.<br>
                            If you shorten the page height...<br>the content appears under the header and footer...<br>and there's no scrollbar.<br>
                            If you shorten the page height...<br>the content appears under the header and footer...<br>and there's no scrollbar.<br>
                            If you shorten the page height...<br>the content appears under the header and footer...<br>and there's no scrollbar.<br>
                            If you shorten the page height...<br>the content appears under the header and footer...<br>and there's no scrollbar.<br>
                        </p>
                        <div class="push"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
```

---

How can the content push the footer down, to make a scrollbar?

(Instead of overlapping and eventually disappearing)?

Comment: What kind of hell are you in that you're developing stuff for IE6?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Throwing all of this out and starting from scratch with modern browsers in mind would probably be the best approach.

Comment: I only agree with both comments. Unfortunately this website will be in China, where IE6 is as common as polluted air.

Comment: I feel your pain, we only got rid of the last IE6 users 3 months ago... legacy embedded kit!

Can you clarify... are you trying to enhance this to work on IE6 AND newer browsers, or is your issue with how it is behaving IN IE6 specifically?

I _think_ you might need to play with adding `overflow:scroll` and a min-height on your vcentre-relative-child class?  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: @Stuffed Marshmallow if you see average statistics of legendary browser IE6 in 2018 0% percent of people are using it. https://www.w3counter.com/trends

Comment: http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/all/china/2018

Comment: js, i actually done exactly what you have and my only fix could be done with JS

Comment: I have considered javascript as a last resort if in a few months the issue is still not resolved. In other words, I am crazy.

Comment: I figured it out